# ImportError cannot import name

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a unittest with the following imports:

```
from LinearProbeTable import Dictionary
import unittest
import string
import random
class TestDictionary(unittest.TestCase):
    (testing code)
```

In LinearProbeTable I import an excecption:

```
from Exceptions import DictFullError
```

The DictFullError is defined as (in Exceptions.py):

```
class DictFullError(Exception):
    pass
```

I get the following traceback when I try to run the test:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm Educational.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 135, in <module>
    module = loadSource(a[0])
  File "/Applications/PyCharm Educational.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 40, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = methods.load()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1220, in load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/andrewsalter/.../Prac 9/Testing/task1_autotest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from LinearProbeTable import Dictionary
  File "/Users/andrewsalter/.../Prac 9/LinearProbeTable.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Exceptions import DictFullError
ImportError: cannot import name 'DictFullError'
```

I don't have a circular dependency, so I'm not sure what's happening.

I'm trying to run this on my laptop, but it worked on my Desktop (I have it all hosted on google drive - I know I should be using Git but I haven't got around to it yet)

EDIT: Could it be due to the fact LinearProbeTable.py is in the parent folder to the testing script?